# Postgresql 8.4 -> 9.1 : ANALYSE VERBOSE; -> out of shared memory

Tags: memory, statistics, postgresql-9.1

**FYI, This question is posted on PG-General mailing list too,**

We have a problem since we migrate from 8.4 to 9.1.

When we play:

```
ANALYSE VERBOSE;
```

( stat on all databases, with 500 tables and 1to DATA in all tables)

We now have this message :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of shared memory Indice : You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

When we was in 8.4, there was no error, there is our specific postgresql.conf configuration on the server:

```
default_statistics_target = 200
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
constraint_exclusion = on
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 7GB
work_mem = 48MB
wal_buffers = 32MB
checkpoint_segments = 64
shared_buffers = 2304MB
max_connections = 150
random_page_cost = 2.0
max_locks_per_transaction = 128 **
```

max_lock_per_transaction was at is default value before (64?), **we already tried to increase it** according to error hint.

We already tried to increase linux shared memory too. Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try lowering `maintenance_work_mem` (try `256MB`) and setting `max_locks_per_transaction` to much higher value e.g. `1024`.